# Triggering action on adding object from admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have a model that holds emails of users who signed up for emails that notify about new articles on the site. Articles are added from the admin panel. I want to figure out how to trigger some function on object addition by admin.

MailingList model

```
class MailingList(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'email: ' + str(self.email)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can use or Django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) to do something after new article is added (post_save signal, for example). Or, if you'd like to do something exactly when new article is saved only from admin, you can override [ModelAdmin.save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods).